# Nil can't be coerced into Fixnum Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

So I have a product page and i must create new products. When creating a new product i hit the error referenced in my title question. (nil can't be....)

app/models => `+'

```
return (((vat_part(discount_percent, date, options) + non_vat_part(discount_percent, date, options))*1.2).round(2)/1.2).round(rounded ? 2 : 1000)
```

I suppose the plus sign is a major cause of this error.

Anyway, I appreciate any hints and advices.

Comment: it is not enough to help you. And the error message is very obvious, to help you to fix it by yourself. Either `vat_part` or `non_vat_part` gives `nil`. And fix those methods by adding proper guards.

Comment: @ArupRakshit exactyly `non_vat_part` produces `nil`

Comment: Perhaps you should modify `non_vat_part` to return `0` instead of `nil`?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? `((total * 1.2).round(2) / 1.2)` seems like it doesn't do anything except introduce some error into `total`, and calling `round` at two different points in a calculation is a great way to produce rounding errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting `nil` to `0` (with `to_i` or `to_f`, depends on your logic):

```
return (((vat_part(discount_percent, date, options).to_i + non_vat_part(discount_percent, date, options).to_i)*1.2).round(2)/1.2).round(rounded ? 2 : 1000)
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know `nil.to_i` produces 0. I was about to post some long a$$ answer using ternary. :-)

Comment: Just remember `.to_i` will round to an integer. You might want decimals hear.